# RE-working sql query with AND/OR based on post values (wordpress site)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to craft a sql query for use in my wordpress site (custom php file) based on values coming from an Ajax POST call.

Now, the code below works perfectly, but I need to rework my AND/OR section for use-cases.

My POST values are 'search', 'rev_pro' and 'prac_type'. At any given time, my call can have any of these three values, so I want to make sure that the query works if only one is fulfilled or if all 3 are fulfilled. In other words, if I have a search value and a rev_pro value, I should get results that satisfy both. But if I have no search value and only have rev_pro and prac_type, then both of those should be considered.

```
    $prefix_post = $wpdb->prefix. "posts";
    $prefix_postmeta = $wpdb->prefix. "postmeta";
    $prefix_ad = $wpdb->prefix. "awpcp_ad_regions";
    $prefix_tr = $wpdb->prefix. "term_relationships";
            
    $search = '';
    if($_POST['search'] != ''){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
    }
            
    $like = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($search) . '%';
            
    $extra_meta = '';
    if($_POST['prac_type'] != ''){
        $prac_type = $_POST['prac_type'];
                
        $extra_meta = " OR ( $prefix_postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s)  ";
    }

    if($_POST['rev_pro'] != ''){
        $rev_pro = $_POST['rev_pro'];
                
        $extra_meta .= " OR ($prefix_postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s )";
    }
                        
    $revLike = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($rev_pro) . '%';
    $pracLike = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like($prac_type) . '%';

    $sqlStatement = "SELECT $prefix_post.ID 
        FROM $prefix_post 
        LEFT JOIN $prefix_ad ON ($prefix_post.ID = $prefix_ad.ad_id)
        INNER JOIN $prefix_postmeta ON ($prefix_post.ID = $prefix_postmeta.post_id)
        WHERE $prefix_post.ID IN ($lid) 
        AND $prefix_postmeta.meta_key in ('_extra_field[38]','_extra_field[34]','_extra_field[35]')
        AND (($prefix_ad.county LIKE %s) 
            OR ($prefix_ad.country LIKE %s)
            OR ($prefix_ad.city LIKE %s)
            OR ($prefix_ad.state LIKE %s)
            OR ($prefix_postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s)
            $extra_meta
            )
        AND $prefix_post.post_type = '_listing' 
        AND $prefix_post.post_status = 'publish'
        GROUP BY $prefix_post.ID 
        ORDER BY $prefix_post.post_date DESC;";

    $sqlStatement  = $wpdb->prepare( $sqlStatement, $like, $like, $like, $like, $like, $revLike, $pracLike );
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If I understand you question, you just need to move your `$extra_meta` outside of the `AND` to a dedicated top level `OR` block. For this kind of debugging, I'd strongly recommend writing SQL by hand and testing it against a database using a tool like phpMyAdmin or similar, bypassing WordPress, PHP and HTTP completely. This way you can inspect the results without that other stuff getting in the way. Once you get it working, then it is pretty easy to patch it back into PHP.